# BOOTSTRAP - MODAL

Tags: bootstrap, modal, href

Una consulta rapida!
Estoy trabajando con un modal boostrap pero cuando hago click no me redirecciona a otro HTMl llamado fotos1.html.

Hay algun error?

```
<a class="portfolio-link" data-remote="fotos1.html"data-toggle="modal" href="fotos1.html" data-target="_blank"> </a>
```

Comment: en otras palabras deseas abrir un modal remoto ó abrir una pagina html en tu modal ?

Comment: aunque no creas tu pregunta soluciono mi duda jajajajaja

Comment: jaja ok suerte..!!

Comment: prueba superada jajaja